# How add days after date

Tags: date, strtotime

This code print 30 dates after now date
`$date = strtotime($year. 'm d'); $endDate = strtotime(($year)."+$dd days");` 
Like

> 24-8-2023 25-8-2023 26-8-2023 """ """ 24-9-2023

I wante print 30 days after 1-1-2023 Like

> 1-1-2023 2-1-2023 3-1-2023 """ """ 30-1-2023 ets
> Share
> Edit
> Delete
> Flag

This code print 30 dates after now date
`$date = strtotime($year. 'm d'); $endDate = strtotime(($year)."+$dd days");` 
Like

> 24-8-2023 25-8-2023 26-8-2023 """ """ 24-9-2023

I wante print 30 days after 1-1-2023 Like

> 1-1-2023 2-1-2023 3-1-2023 """ """ 30-1-2023 ets